# Parse and mapping data in tableview with Alamofire and SwifrtJSON with completion handler(@escaping)

Tags: swift, parsing, alamofire, swifty-json, completionhandler

I have data models. I make a request and get JSON. But I want to use the completion handler to add data to the table. How do I save data and display it in a tableview? I didn't use the entire data model for the test.

This is my data model

[Text](https://gyazo.com/eb40342763e02b747e3ccd0d1dd4cbf1)

This is my function for parsing and mapping

```
class Network {
    let baseUrl = URL(string:"https://ppbet-327310.appspot.com/api/games")
    func getCity(completion: @escaping([WelcomeElement]) -> ()) {
        guard let url = baseUrl else {return}
        AF.request(url, method: .get).responseJSON { (response) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                guard let data = response.data else {return}
                let json = try! JSON(data: data)
                let arrayCount = json.array?.count ?? 0
                for i in 0..<arrayCount {
                    let name = json[i]["name"].string ?? "N/A"
                    if let betTypes = json[i]["betTypes"].array {
                        for i in 0..<betTypes.count {
                            guard let outcomesCounter = betTypes[i]["outcomesCounter"].int else {return}
                            guard let nameBet = betTypes[i]["name"].string else {return}     
                        }
                    }   
                    if let leagues = json[i]["leagues"].array {
                        for i in 0..<leagues.count {
                            guard let nameLeagues = leagues[i]["name"].string else {return}
                            if let events = leagues[i]["events"].array {
                                for i in 0..<events.count {
                                    guard let team1 = events[i]["team1"].string else {return}
                                    guard let team2 = events[i]["team2"].string else {return}
                                    guard let score1 = events[i]["score1"].string else {return}
                                    guard let score2 = events[i]["score2"].string else {return}
                                    if let betTypes = events[i]["betTypes"].array {
                                        for i in 0..<betTypes.count {
                                            guard let nameBetTypes = betTypes[i]["name"].string else {return}
                                            
                                            if let outcomesBetTypes = betTypes[i]["outcomes"].array {
                                                for i in 0..<outcomesBetTypes.count {
                                                    guard let name = outcomesBetTypes[i]["name"].string else {return}
                                                    guard let coefficient = outcomesBetTypes[i]["coefficient"].string else {return}
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(/*????)*/)
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To be honest there is so much missing from this that it's difficult to give you an answer.  It would probably be best for you to do some reading on how to parse JSON and instantiate objects.  I would recommend reading about the Codable or Decodable protocols as that would really allow you to clean up this parsing block and make future changes more manageable.

Comment: A better starting point might be to use quicktype.io to generate `Decodable` types from your JSON, then feed those types into Alamofire's `responseDecodable` method to automatically parse your response, and access the type's properties.